# Why does window.onload get called for a refresh only some of the time?

Tags: javascript

To be clear my JavaScript code works. I use window.onload to call an initial function that gets the time and date and sends it to a remote server via an XMLHttpRequest.  At some point, while debugging, I reduced the initial function simply to display the time and date on the screen, and nothing else.

I found when I did the latter a refresh did not always cause a window.onload even to be called. Even using Crtl+F5 rarely changed the time. Finally put the rest of the code back in (calling the server) and every refresh works every time!

Below is the code that does not seem to call the onload event for every refresh.  But if you remove the return statement surrounded by comments...every refresh calls window.onload.

While I shouldn't be complaining that my full code works, I would like to find out why the simple version did not?

```
<script>
window.onload = loadDoc();

function loadDoc() {

var today = new Date();
var date = today.getFullYear()+'-'+
  ( (today.getMonth()+1)<10 ? "0"+(today.getMonth()+1) : (today.getMonth()+1) ) +'-'+ 
  ( (today.getDate() +1)<10 ? "0"+(today.getDate() +1) : (today.getDate() +1) );
var time = ( (today.getHours())<10 ? "0"+(today.getHours()) : (today.getHours()) ) + ":" + 
            ( (today.getMinutes())<10 ? "0"+(today.getMinutes()) : (today.getMinutes()) ) + ":" + 
           ( (today.getSeconds())<10 ? "0"+(today.getSeconds()) : (today.getSeconds()) );

var dateTime = date+' '+time;

  document.getElementById("myBanner").value=dateTime;

///////////////////////////////
return; //////remove this return and every refresh calls this function
///////////////////////////////

  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200)  {
      document.getElementById("myBanner").value = this.responseText;
    }
  };
  string = "http://example.com/cgi-bin/perly.pl?b=1&d=" + dateTime;
  xhttp.open("GET", string, true);
  document.getElementById("myBanner").value="sent";
  xhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: `window.onload = loadDoc()` You wanted `window.onload = loadDoc`. Here you are just setting the return value of loadDoc (`undefined`)  as the event handler, i.e it won't do anything, and won't wait for the page to load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does not actually attach an event listener to the onload event handler. Instead, you're setting the value of `window.onload` to the return value of `loadDoc()` - which means that `loadDoc()` is run, to calculate the return value; but it is run as soon at is encountered instead of when `onload` should be called.

I assume adding the `HttpRequest` delayed the function long enough to run at the correct timing, wheras the simple code was run before it should have been.

To correctly attach the event, use

```
window.onload = (event) => { loadDoc(); };
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event for reference

Example: loadDoc is run immediately, before `myBanner` is loaded, resulting in `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null`

```html
<script>
 window.onload = loadDoc(); 
 
 function loadDoc() {
 
 var mesage = "Hello World"
 
   document.getElementById("myBanner").innerHTML=mesage;
 
 return; 
 }
</script>
<body>
 <div id="myBanner"></div>
</body>
```

Event Handler is attached properly, `loadDoc` is run after all elements are loaded:

```html
<script>
 window.onload = (event) => { loadDoc(); }
 
 function loadDoc() {
 
 var mesage = "Hello World"
 
   document.getElementById("myBanner").innerHTML=mesage;
 
 return; 
 }
</script>
<body>
 <div id="myBanner"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess your code throws an error that's when it proceeds after the return. I don't know if you already declare this part `string = "http://example.com/cgi-bin/perly.pl?b=1&d=" + dateTime;` It seems you just used this `string` but you did not declare it.

Comment: That was left out while I was formatting the post, it is in my code though.  Thank you.